# datepicker() not working using jquery in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hi in the below code datepicker() is not working using jquery.But separately it's working fine.

After adding the code into my page it's not working this is my sample code.

**html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Admission Form</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admissionform.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
  </script>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
</head>
<body>
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Youre are includin 2 various jquery check it `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` may be its conflicting each othere

Comment: I think you are using "." instead for "#". As I notice "datepicker" is your element Id not class.

Comment: then also it not working

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple calls to jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Leave only only call (before any use of jQuery). Also check DevTools console for other errors (if any).

Also, you have `<input id="datepicker">` but call datepicker for class selector `.date-picker`

Comment: @hspcare Any errors in console? Removed duplicate jQuery call?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Input element is with ID datepicker but you have used the class selector to create datepicker

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker();
```

use id selector

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

Check Console for errors

You have used 2 jquery files which might also cause some issue

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function it's giving this error